# When i run new terminal display something wrong

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-18.04

When i run new terminal it show not understandable think

How stop this[image]

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: But, why there are tags from Ubuntu?

Comment: Because there can be questions about programming that are related to Ubuntu. Your question is not. The [help] provides information about what is proper to ask here. [ubuntu.se] was created specifically for non-programming questions about Ubuntu, and [su] was created specifically for general computer related questions that are not programming-related. Some tags still exist from before those sites were created, but that doesn't make them automatically appropriate to use here. They're just leftovers.